# pass socket to child process

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

My project has two programs: Parent and Child.

In Parent: has one socket waiting connection from client. When Parent accepts connection, it generates Child process and passes socket to Child.

```
SOCKET newSock = accept(listenSock, 0, 0);
char cmd[1024];
sprintf(cmd, "%s %d", "Child.exe", newSock);
result = CreateProcess( NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);
```

Client and Child process transfer data successfully.

But when I searches Google and some people wrote that : must call function WSADuplicateSocket(), after that pass socket to child process.

Pleas help me show the different between the two ways?
If I don't call WSADuplicateSocket() whether my program has any error or not?

Comment: `sprintf()` is dangerous, since it can result in buffer overflows with untrusted data.  You should use `_snprintf_s` instead (or `snprintf` on non-Windows systems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting Parameter `bInheritHandles` in CreateProcess to TRUE you allow a child process to get all inheritable handle. Socket handles are inheritable [always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058911/can-tcp-socket-handles-be-set-not-inheritable). So you don't need any extra call.

WSADuplicateSocket is required only if you handle was not inherited (socket was created after child process start or `bInheritHandles` is `FALSE` in `CreateProcess`)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, a `SOCKET` on Windows is a handle (ie a pointer) and thus is subject to 32/64-bit byte sizes, so `%d` is not adequate if your app runs on a 64-bit system. You would have to use `%p` instead.

Aside from that, `WSADuplicateSocket()` is the correct approach.  MSDN says as much:

[Shared Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740478%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The WSADuplicateSocket function is introduced to
>   enable socket sharing across processes.