# WINAPI RegisterApplicationRestart not clearing open sockets

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, networking, server

I have a server for a game I am making, and I use

```
RegisterApplicationRestart(GetCommandLine(), 0);
```

so that when the server crashes for unforeseen reasons, it restarts itself.

However, I am having issues with how this handles the open listener sockets I have on the application.

The server code goes through a set of port numbers and opens a listener socket on the first available port. However, when the application encounters a fatal error and restarts itself the listener socket on the previously chosen port is not closed, so every time the application restarts the port number used increases and the previously used ports become 'dead' listeners that accept connections but are not tied to any of my code.

Is there a way to force those open sockets to close when the application restarts itself?

Comment: None of the functions you mention are standard C++, so that part is lacking from your question, making it impossible to answer. That said, consider something like `supervisord`.

Comment: They are standard Windows API functions, so it should be possible to answer. Edited the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Windows is generally very good at cleaning up crashed processes.  It will close any open sockets.  Are you sure that your server is actually crashing?

Comment: @PeterRuderman I'm forcing the server to crash by assigning a null pointer and attempting to access it, and I can see that the server does indeed crash and a new process is spawned. And I can see on the output log that the previously used port number are still registered as being in use. 

However, as soon as I kill the new process myself, the ports are no longer in use.

Answer (score 0):

There’re several possible reasons for this.

Could be your application creates child processes with [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) or wrappers like [`system`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=vs-2017), sockets handles are inherited by the child, and the child process still lives when your parent process crashes and is restarted.

If that’s your case, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12058913/126995) for a couple of workarounds.

Comment: As far as I'm aware I am not calling CreateProcess anywhere in my application. Closing the application manually does close those sockets, it is only when the application crashes and restarts itself that the sockets are not closed, which implies that it is not due to child processes. Unless the new instance of itself it creates through RegisterApplicationRestart counts as a child process.