# closesocket in parent and child?

Tags: c, windows, winsock2

As far as I understand, if you create a socket on POSIX-related systems, then spawn a child which inherits that socket fd, apparently you should call `close` on that fd in each process when that process is done with it, as the fd is internally reference counted, and I suppose that reference count is incremented on `fork`, and `close` then decrements it again.

Is this the same with Windows, should you call `closesocket` in each process that has a copy of that socket, or do you only call it in one process, when all processes are done with it?

**Edit:** the question marked as a duplicate of this one is relevant ([Are TCP SOCKET handles inheritable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847793/are-tcp-socket-handles-inheritable)), as it suggests that inheriting SOCKETs is error-prone, but it also suggests that it's still possible. In which case, if one persists regardless of the possible errors, then it would be good if this question had an answer; should one `closesocket` in all processes, or just the parent?

**Second edit:** I believe this question is answered in [the documentation for `WSADuplicateSocketA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaduplicatesocketa):

> A process can call closesocket on a duplicated socket and the descriptor will become deallocated. The underlying socket, however, will remain open until closesocket is called by the last remaining descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't see sockets on Windows as file descriptors, so they don't get inherited the same way. See this link for the full answer to your question: [Are TCP SOCKET handles inheritable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847793/are-tcp-socket-handles-inheritable)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I may have accepted a bit prematurely though; the link indicates that treating SOCKETs as inheritable is error-prone, but possible. If we do treat them as inheritable despite the problems, then I'd still be glad to see an answer to my original question; should closesocket then be called in all processes, or just the parent?